# loginProcessingUrl Spring Boot Not working

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, spring-mvc

My problem is the .loginProcessingUrl is not working it always returns the .failureUrl

The config below is an adapted version from this tutorial: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fGJkc2Cu1M&list=PL82C6-O4XrHejlASdecIsroNEbZFYo_X1&index=22](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/login/**","/register","/clubs","/css/**","/js/**") // this url(s) will not be block by the Spring security
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin(form -> form    // Login config start from here
                            .loginPage("/login")  // url of login page
                            .defaultSuccessUrl("/clubs") // when the login success web will be redirect to /clubs
                            .loginProcessingUrl("/login") // where the login will be processed (this will hanlde the post method.)
                            .failureUrl("/login?error=true") // this will handle the error.
                            .permitAll()   // Login config ends here
                    ).logout( logout -> logout
                            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll() // path of the logout
                    );
            return http.build();
        }

}
```

```
<section layout:fragment="body" class="py-5">
        <div class="container px-5 my-5">
            <div th:if="${param.error}" class="alert alert-danger">
                Invalid username and password.
            </div>
            <div th:if="${param.logout}" class="alert alert-success">
                You have been logged out.
            </div>
            <div class="row gx-5">
                <form method="post" role="form" th:action="@{/login}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="username"
                               name="username"
                               placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        <input type="password"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="password"
                               name="password"
                               placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                    <a th:href="@{/register}">Don't have an account already? Register here.</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```